# How to lock file from system changes using BusyBox (on a Synology NAS)

Tags: linux, synology, busybox

I have a specific file that an app is randomly changing and that I need to be immutable. I.e. stop the system from rewriting the file.

Considering that the NAS has BusyBox for ssh access, how can I do this?

Thank you

edit: chmod isn't not working for this

Answer (score 0):

You should make that file Read Only,

```
$ chmod 444 <file>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that chmod wasn't cutting it. `hive> chmod 444 .ui_info
hive> ls -l .ui_info 
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            54 Sep 24 10:19 .ui_info
hive> ls -l .ui_info 
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            54 Sep 24 10:19 .ui_info
hive> ls -l .ui_info 
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            54 Sep 24 10:27 .ui_info`

Comment: Ok that's interesting. How is this app accessing the file ? And also what is the file system your file is on ?

Comment: Yeah, this is not my area of expertise... :) This is a Synology NAS (linux based with BusyBox, this I know), and it a simple text file that one of the NAS' packages creates and rewrites.

Comment: What file system is in use ?  What do you see for the volume your file is on when you use the 'mount' command ?

Comment: This is what I see : `/dev/root on / type ext4 (defaults)
/sys on /sys type sysfs (0)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (gid=4,mode=620)
/tmp on /tmp type tmpfs (0)
/run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)
/dev/shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (uid=0,gid=0,mode=0755,size=4k)
/dev/bus/usb on /proc/bus/usb type bind (bind)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (0)
/dev/vg1000/lv on /volume1 type ext4 (usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0,synoacl)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (0)`.